# Get value of selected option in angular

Tags: angularjs

I want to get the value of the selected `city` inside `{{cities}}` (e.g. Mumbai / Pune). This is what iv'e tried so far:

**html**

```
<select ng-model="cities" ng-options="store as store for (store,city) in stores">
    <option value="" ng-selected="index">select city</option>
</select>

<div>
  {{cities}}    
</div>
```

**js**

```
$scope.stores = {
    "Mumbai": [
        {
            area: "Kurla",
            storeName: "Name 2",
            address: "Adresrs",
            phone1: "2345",
            phone2: "345235"
        },
        {
            area: "Kalyan",
            storeName: "Name @3",
            address: "Aressf",
            phone1: "2352345",
            phone2: ""
        },
        {
            area: "Kharghar",
            storeName: "Test 1",
            address: "wert",
            phone1: "3456345",
            phone2: ""
        }
    ],
    "Pune": [
        {
            area: "test",
            storeName: "Name 2",
            address: "Address 2",
            phone1: "234423423",
            phone2: "234234b"
        },
        {
            area: "test2",
            storeName: "Name 1",
            address: "test 4 address",
            phone1: "8108156730",
            phone2: ""
        },
        {
            area: "test3",
            storeName: "test Address",
            phone1: "4234234",
            phone2: ""
        }
    ]
}
```

#### demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbBBrw

Comment: As useful as off-site demos are, please include the relevant code here as well.  Also, it's not clear what your actual questions/problem is.  The demo works.

Comment: in your code `{{cities}}` are OUTSIDE scope of controller, move it inside DIV and suddenly it will work

Comment: I am sorry could not explain it. Thanks for your involvement. I got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better `ng-options` syntax, `value as text for (key, val) in object`

```
ng-options="store as store for (store,city) in stores"
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEooda

Comment: It's not an answer to the question

Comment: @maurycy -- It displays the selected city..?

Comment: @tymeJV Yes, but I think he means that isn't the focus of the answer.

Comment: @KnownColor -- And what is the focus then?

Comment: No matter what syntax You use it will not work until the `{{cities}}` will be in controller scope, simple changing syntax does not fix the problem, that why I say it's not an answer to question, ignoring the irrelevant part it turns into link only answer

Comment: @maurycy -- Um, `{{cities}}` is inside the controller scope...if it wasn't, nothing would display and you would see `{{cities}}` displayed in the HTML. So no, that's not right.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<select ng-model="cities" ng-options="store as store for (store,city) in stores">...
```